# Почему выводится ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null?

Tags: javascript

```js
class ToDo{
 
 inputToDo(){
  this.list = document.createElement('div');
  this.list.className = 'list';
  this.creat = document.getElementById('out');
  this.creat.append(this.list);
  this.but = "<li class='li-bottom'><button id='del'>Закрыть</button></li>";
  this.result = "<ul><li><h2>" + this.title + "</h2></li>" + "<li>" + this.txt + "</li>" + this.but;
  this.list.innerHTML = this.result;
  if(document.getElementById('del').onclick){
   alert("sdf");
  }
 }
 
 checkText(){
  this.textCount = 530;
  this.titlCount = 27;
  this.title = document.getElementById('titl').value;
  this.txt = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  
  if(this.title.length <= this.titlCount && !this.title.length == 0){
   if(this.txt.length <= this.textCount && !this.txt.length == 0){
    this.inputToDo();
   }else{
    alert('Задача не должена превышать ' + this.textCount + ' символов и не должен ровняться нулю');
   }
  }else{
   alert('Заголовок не должен превышать ' + this.titlCount + ' символов и не должен ровняться нулю');
  }
 }
 
 deletToDo(){
  this.list.remove();
 }
}

window.onload = function(){
 var todo = new ToDo();
 
 document.getElementById('push').onclick = function(){
  todo.checkText();
 }
 
 document.getElementById('del').onclick = function(){
  todo.deletToDo();
 }
}
```

```css
html,
body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #15502f;
}

header{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

header h1{
 color: white;
 text-shadow: 0 4px 3px black;
}

main{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}

.inp{
 padding: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.inp form{
 width: 303px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}

.inp textarea{
 resize: none;
    text-align: center;
}

form input{
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

.out{
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list{
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 25px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px black;
}


.list:hover{
 box-shadow: 0 0 25px black;
 transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

ul{
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.list li{
 text-align: center;
}

.li-bottom{
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 padding-top: 15px;
}

li:nth-child(1){
 height: 27px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
li:nth-child(2){
 height: 288px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ToDo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>ToDo List</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section class="inp">
        <form method="#" action="#">
          <input placeholder="Заголовок" type="text" id="titl">
          <textarea rows="10" cols="40" placeholder="Задача" id="txt"></textarea>
          <input value="Добавить" type="submit" id="push">
        </form>
      </section>
      <section class="out" id="out">
        
      </section>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Элемент с `id='del'` создается при каждом вызове метода `inputToDo`.

В приведенном коде указанный метод нигде не вызывается, следовательно в любой момент времени `document.getElementById('del')` будет возвращать `null`.

Answer (score 0):

В момент вызова

```
document.getElementById('del').onclick = function(){
    todo.deletToDo();
}
```

элемента[ов] с `id='del'` не существует. Не говоря уже о том, что Вы их создаете больше одного.

Comment: Почему не существует если даже сама кнопка появляется при создании элемента? Создаю 1